# Definite integral $\int_{-1}^{1} \frac {z-Ru} {z^2+R^2-2Rzu}\ du.$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

$$\int\limits_{-1}^{1} \frac{z-Ru}{z^2 + R^2 - 2Rzu}\,du$$

I tried the method of substitution:
$$
     x = z^2+R^2+2Rzu \qquad
\implies \qquad dx = 2Rzdu 
$$
But couldn't  find my way.

Comment: Is the integral this:
$$
\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{z - Ru}{z^2 + R^2  - 2Rzu}\, du
$$
?

Comment: @MattiP.  Yes that is what I meant

Comment: Use mathjax to edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to see that $z$ and $R$ cannot be simultaneously $0.$ But one of $z$ or $R$ may be $0.$ In which cases the integral is easy to solve. So let us first assume that $z,R \neq 0.$

Then observe that $$\begin{align*} \frac {z-Ru} {z^2+R^2 - 2Rzu} & = \frac {1} {2z} \frac {z^2 + R^2 - 2 Ruz} {z^2+R^2 -2Ruz} + \frac {\frac {z} {2} - \frac {R^2} {2z}} {z^2+R^2-2Ruz}. \\ & = \frac {1} {2z} + \frac {\frac {z} {2} - \frac {R^2} {2z}} {z^2+R^2-2Ruz}. \end{align*}$$

So $$\begin{align*} \int\limits_{-1}^{1} \frac {z-Ru} {z^2+R^2 - 2Rzu}\ du & = \frac {1} {2z} \int\limits_{-1}^{1} du + \left (\frac {z} {2} - \frac {R^2} {2z} \right ) \int\limits_{-1}^{1} \frac {du} {z^2+R^2-2Ruz}. \\ & = \frac {1} {z} - \frac {1} {2Rz} \left ( \frac {z} {2} - \frac {R^2} {2z} \right ) \int\limits_{-1}^{1} \frac {du} {u-a}. \end{align*}$$

where $a = \frac {z^2 + R^2} {2Rz}.$ Can you proceed now?